wifi adapter not recognized anymore
I'm at my wits end. Also I'm really new with ubuntu. I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.4
Thing is, my ASUS PCE AX-3000 Wifi card doesn't always get recognized.
If I shut down the PC, remove the card physically, reboot the system and then do the same thing backwards the wifi works no problemo. Until the next reboot that is.
If it doesn't work:
thelshw -c network command only shows the ethernet adapter
wifi also doesn't show on lspci
At first I thought it might have to do with some BIOS settings like fastboot, but i can't find anything like this on my boards BIOS (MSI pro B650M-P)
Anyone got any hints?

Maybe your system doesn't remove power from the wifi card when you shut down?  What happens if you remove the card, then reinsert it immediately before rebooting?  And what happens if you use halt to stop the system, then hold down the power button to force a power off event.  For reference, halt will stop processes, unmount filesystems, and otherwise shut down the system.  However it doesn't power off, it just disables the CPU and leaves the system powered on.

Thanks for the inputs.
Unfortunately neither idea helps.
I also forgot to mention that my PC is connected to a mainpowerswitch. So its completely of power when not in use.

OK, so: 1) shutdown 2) remove card 3) insert card, 4) power on doesn't work?  And 1) shutdown 2) remove card 3) power on (and notice the missing card?), 4) shutdown 5) insert card 6) power on (and notice newly inserted card) does work?

Sorry, I think I was wrong about my conclusion.
I did some more tests today.
The problem seems to be connected with my main power switch. So when i shut down and turn the power completely off, the next time I boot, there's no wifi.
Then I just reboot and there it is.
Guess I never tried that before, because i generally turn the power off, especially when i opened the computer.
I searched again if there were any strange settings in the bios but didn't found anything. Also there aren't many power settings in ubuntu, right?
While I might live with this "workaround" it really bugs me.
